# Removing image alt text with black borders in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

When i open my site in firefox it shows img alt attribute in a black box(see attached image).
it only shows just for a second and when image starts loading its gone.

i want to remove this.

[image]

this is my html code

```
<a href="url"><img alt="alt text" width="650" height="241" src="src url" /></a>
```

it only shows in firefox.

i have tried using  this css code

```
a img {
    border: 0;
}
```

but this did not help.

how i can remove this?

Comment: used img{outline:0;) and a{outline:0;}

Comment: now you can go to html part and remove alt tag on img tag

Comment: Actually, it is bad practice to remove `ALT` attributes on `IMG` tags. They are important for accessibility and indexability (by search engines, f.e.) and that matters. One thing is never having had `ALT` attributes there in the first place, because you didn't have time, but people who remove `ALT` attributes do a real disservice to their users. Please don't remove `ALT`s, especially if your argument is that your time is money.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that you can't. The longer answer is that you shouldn't.

You are approaching this in an entirely wrong manner. Expectedly, I guess - in this day and age not many care to think why tag attributes like `ALT` exist at all, and why Firefox bothers with borders before it renders images. But you should know these things if you want to be serious about web design. They are there for a reason. It is because people are different and user agents are different - some people cannot even see images that well, while they either may read or are *read to* the page contents by a screen reader, which cannot discern pixel content all that well. Also, in some scenarios (academic, scientific), user agents are configured to **ignore** images, only displaying ALT content, focusing on textual content instead.

If you take the above into consideration, you can make decisions based on these facts - what does your image actually do? Is it important for your users to see it at all? If it is indeed a picture that is at the heart of it, then you shouldn't bother with how it will be shown to your users - rest assured, they will see it and hopefully be happy.

The `IMG` element is for image-based data that is part of the **content** of the document you serve, not part of its style. This is an absolutely essential knowledge, that many never think about. Separators, hyperlink icons before `A` elements, huge banners on top of your pages, buttons for forms - all this is **not** part of content, it seldom carries meaning to the reader. That alone decides if these should be put in there with say, CSS instead. You use `IMG` element for photos, drawings, logos, illustrations and such.

In other words, if it is a decorative part of your web page design, you should instead think whether a background image will do - **it will also eliminate your border and ALT problem entirely.**
This is all you can do - no CSS will and should rob the user of your page(s) of accessibility just because **you** don't like borders. Remember - your webpages are **not your webpages**, they are viewed by your users. Same goes for user agents - they use theirs, and they prefer to set it up their way. Whether you yourself like borders is of little value or concern to them. Give them possibility to make the best use of them. Graphic design is indirectly about compromise - we want to better convey a message of our choosing using methods we have available, while respecting their choices and preferences. Web-design is much because of this a walk on the edge of a knife.

```
<div style="background-image: url(forest.jpg); width: 600px; height: 200px;">
    Tree hugging, anyone?
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but here is 2017 update with CSS only solution using pseudo elements.

```css
img:after {  
  content: attr(alt);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <img src="//placehold.foo/200x200" alt="Remove border from this alt text" />
```